# performing async concurrent api requests in python

Tags: python, api, get-request

I have this code:

```
import requests
import json
import psycopg2
import time
import csv

epics = []
with open('cmd.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        epics.append(row[0])

# print(epics)

for epic in epics:
    url = 'https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/positions/otc'
    params = {
        "epic": epic,
        "expiry": "DFB",
        "direction": "BUY",
        "size": "1",
        "orderType": "MARKET",
        # "timeInForce":'null',
        # "level":'null',
        "guaranteedStop": "false",
        # "stopLevel": 'null',
        # "stopDistance":'null',
        # "trailingStop":'null',
        # "trailingStopIncrement":'null',
        "forceOpen": "true",
        # "limitLevel": 'null',
        # "limitDistance":'null',
        # "quoteId":'null',
        "currencyCode": "GBP"
    }

    # Trade submission
    time.sleep(1.5)
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
    print(url)
    result = resp.json()
    print(result)
```

epics is just a csv list of values which the loop iterates through and sends a post request for each epic. However as I am using requests its taking too long to iterate through the epic list. I would like to post 100 concurrent requests per second as this is the SLA from the website. Each request should be for a unique epic.

Can someone kindly provide guidance as to how to do this

Comment: Python by default runs single-threaded. Since there's a `sleep` of 1.5s, there's no way if could do more than 1 request per second. If you want parellelism, you should try to use either `threading` or `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Thanks @white, can you please provide a code example that shows how to do it please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

First wrap you code into a function like this.

```
def my_function(epic):
    url = 'https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/positions/otc'
    params = {
        "epic": epic,
        "expiry": "DFB",
        "direction": "BUY",
        "size": "1",
        "orderType": "MARKET",
        # "timeInForce":'null',
        # "level":'null',
        "guaranteedStop": "false",
        # "stopLevel": 'null',
        # "stopDistance":'null',
        # "trailingStop":'null',
        # "trailingStopIncrement":'null',
        "forceOpen": "true",
        # "limitLevel": 'null',
        # "limitDistance":'null',
        # "quoteId":'null',
        "currencyCode": "GBP"
    }

    # Trade submission
    time.sleep(1.5)
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
    print(url)
    result = resp.json()
    print(result)
```

Next you need to pass the list of what you want into the function.

Use the multiprocessing module and syntax to feed the list to the function. This uses multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(my_function, epics)
```

You can also do something like this which uses multiprocessing with multithreading.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

max_requests = 100

# compute number of processes in our pool
# the lesser of length of list to process and the number of cores we have
pool_size = min(max_requests, cpu_count(), len(epics))

# create process pool based on number of cpu cores
process_pool = Pool(pool_size)

# create thread pool
thread_pool = ThreadPool(int(max_requests/pool_size))
worker = partial(my_function, process_pool)

# run the final function
thread_pool.map(worker, epics)
```